# How to i merge two results in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have two `excel source` 1st is giving me `date` value and 2nd is giving me `price` value from excel sheet.

Now i need to `insert` these `two values` `into one table` please tell me how can i do this?

I have used `merge join` but it is giving me error `input must be sorted` that i can't as it excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can [define a sort on an excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137653.aspx)

Comment: yes i did that now i'm having 2 values which is coming from source 1 and source2 and sort it but problem is these two values are inserted into table one by one
please see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7488320/428073

Answer (score 1):

Well personally, I would put each Excel file into it's own staging table. Then I would use a SQL query that joins the two tables as the source for my insert to the production tables.

Comment: Well, this depends on the amount of data he has on the excel file. If it's millions of records, he is better of following your suggestion and sorting on the db, since sorting on memory will be too costly. But if he isn't really sorting that much data, then the extra step will be unnecessary.

Comment: I would NEVER do an SSIS package without staging tables. It makes it much easier to see what the problem is if something goes wrong. It also allows you to turn off the data flow that does the final import until you are sure everything else is right.

Comment: With my suggestion you don't actually  have to sort because you use a SQL query as the source for the final import rather than a merge join.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the input from each source, you have to sort it prior to merging it.

You can sort the input from an Excel source, from any source, because the sort is performed with the data on memory. Its an element in the Toolbar.

Check this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137653.aspx

Comment: @ashuthinks I see you solved your problem, the good thing about SSIS its that there are many way to solve any particular issue. The bad thing is that its hard to identify the best way.